# No funciona dropdown en angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular5, bootstrap-4

estoy desarrollando una app en angular 5 y tengo 2 dropdown de bootstrap (como se muestra en la imagen). la cuestión es que el primero funciona bien pero el segundo al hacerle clic da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
at c.t.toggle (scripts.bundle.js:9)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (scripts.bundle.js:9)
at Function.each (scripts.bundle.js:2)
at w.fn.init.each (scripts.bundle.js:2)
at w.fn.init.c._jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (scripts.bundle.js:9)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (scripts.bundle.js:9)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (scripts.bundle.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.y.handle (scripts.bundle.js:2)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando bootstrap 4.1.3 y jquery 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que te falta la librería de popper.js.

Para instalarla, introduce el siguiente comando:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Verifica en el archivo `angular.json` los siguientes registros:

```
"scripts": [  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"]
```